# SonarLint authentication not working when using Azure Active Directory

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

My set up is the following SonarQube 6.0 + Nginx (two docker containers) hosted on a machine on azure.
I've configured the sonar-auth-aad and it's working like a charm in the browser.
I've added the self signed certificate to the store of the local machine so I don't get an error anymore.
My machine has Vs2015 update 3 and the latest version as of today for sonarlint.
When I try to connect to the server using my AAD logins, doesn't work, although it works with plain sonarqube credentials.
Is it something not supported yet or can I configure something in order to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're providing the ability from SonarLint to connect to a SonarQube server with a standard login/password just for backward compatibility reasons with SonarQube 4.5. But the official way to establish this connection is by :

1. Generating a user authentication token in SonarQube (See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token)
2. Configure SonarLint to use this token (and not a login/password)

From there you'll manage to have SonarLint for Visual Studio establishing a connection with your SonarQube server.

Comment: works like a charm thanks! Only tricky thing is you have to use the token as the login and nothing as the password